# Custom story-node-form.tpl.php not working

Tags: 7, theming

I have created a custom node add form for `story` content type. Though this appears as expected but do not working. 
Problem is when i click on the `Submit` button then this form just redirect me again in `node/add/story` path instead creating the story page!
Here is what i have did (Here i have used bartik theme):

> **template.php**

```
    function bartik_theme() {
    return array(
    'story_node_form' => array(
    'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
    'template' => 'story-node-form',
    'render element' => 'form',
    ),
    );
```

> **story-node-form.tpl.php**

```
<div class='story-form'>
<div><?php print drupal_render($form['title']); ?></div>
<div><?php print drupal_render($form['body']); ?></div>
<div><?php print drupal_render($form['actions']); ?></div>
<div><?php print drupal_render($form['additional_settings']); ?></div>
<div><?php print drupal_render($form['actions']); ?></div>
</div>
```

Now if i click on the Submit button then this story creating form just redirect me again in `node/add/story` path instead creating the story page! What i am missing here? Thanks

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing stuff like that in the theme layer. You want to create a custom form use the form api inside of a custom module or modify the existing form using hook_form_alter also in a custom module not the theme. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7

Comment: It's recommended to do this in the theme layer, actually. You're just missing the hidden input fields like the form CSRF token, the form's ID, etc. Try adding `<?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>` in your tpl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by doing `<?php print kpr($form); ?>` and put all the hidden input fields in the form like token, form_id etc that worked!